# Кастомный адаптер для спиннера

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

Сделал кастомный адаптер для спиннера. При раскрытии спиннера метод getDropDownView вызывается непрерывно циклически, даже если список не трогать. Так ведь не должно быть? Почему так происходит? Вот код:

```
MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_row, R.id.tvSpinnerRow, spinnerList);
final Spinner spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

И сам адаптер:

```
public class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        public MyArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, @NonNull List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getRowView(position, convertView, parent);
        }

        @Override
        public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            return getRowView(position, convertView, parent);
        }


        public View getRowView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row, parent, false);
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvSpinnerRow);
            tv.setText(spinnerList.get(position));

            return view;
        }
    }
```

Comment: что значит "вызывается непрерывно циклически"? в приведенном коде нет объяснения

Comment: Просто спамит, не останавливаясь. Сейчас заметил, что если спиннер расположить повыше, и он не будет вынужден раскрываться вверх, то всё становится нормально. Там снизу BottomNavigation, может в нём дело, не понял пока, завтра буду дальше искать. Но от расположения точно зависит, как ни странно.

Comment: Расположение в макете имел в виду

Comment: ну я не вижу в коде, что "вызывает его непрерывно циклически". Всё, что приведено должно работать. Возможно у вас где-то прописан его вызов в другом месте. "Спамит не останавливаясь"="Вызывает непрерывно циклически"=ноль информации. Что вы имеете ввиду? Он постоянно переоткрывается? Значит ищете код, отвечающий за это

Comment: Сейчас воспроизвёл проблему в новом пустом проекте. Буквально 2 минуты: New Project, сделать Navigation Drawer Activity, в content_main.xml добавить спиннер, в MainActivity.java - нехитрый код, который я привёл выше. Если спиннер расположить внизу экрана и что-то выводить в лог в getRowView, то лог будет спамиться до бесконечности после открытия спиннера. При чем если спиннер сдвинуть повыше, то такого не происходит. В spinnerList поставил 5 произвольных строчек для теста. Проблема проявляется только в Navigation Drawer Activity, в других - проблемы нет. Неужели это какой-то баг студии?